# Breakpoint A breakpoint has been reached. How should I investigate this issue further?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I am currently working on a WPF application that is currently in production and we have a case of two users having a crash at the application start that I still cannot explain.

[image: Application crash breakpoint has been reached]

The application shows the first view of the application and is correctly displayed (so the translation service works, this implies that the application seems to be initialized correctly, the IoC is initialized, etc...) the error shows at the same time, clicking on OK closes the application.

The weird thing is that this is the first crash occurence we had that did not log anything in our log files.
We have added an event on the `DispatcherUnhandledException` on the `App.xaml.cs` to log exceptions that are not managed in our view models layer and log them and safely shutdown the application. Here is the event in detail :

```
private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    if (!isFatalErrorCatched)
    {
        isFatalErrorCatched = true;
        try
        {
            var logger = Mvx.Resolve<ILogManager>().GetLogger(this.GetType());
            logger.Error(e.Exception);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Avoid propagation of exception
        }
#if DEBUG
#pragma warning disable S2228
        Console.Write(e.Exception.Message);
#pragma warning restore S2228
#endif

        MessageBox.Show("Your application encountered a fatal error and cannot continue.", "Application Crash", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        this.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Please note that the boolean `isFatalErrorCatched` is just here to avoid managing multiple time an error.
We add the event during `Application_Startup` in the `App.xaml.cs`

```
this.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
```

We have tried a lot of things such as :

- Repairing .NET
- Repairing Registry
- Comparing .dll in installation folder
- Look at the Event Viewer of windows (nothing visible there either)

Here is some additionnal information on what we are using in the application if it provides any additionnal help :

- MvvmCross 4.2.2
- .NET 4.5.1

The users are on Windows 10.

I will soon do a remote control session with the user and I will be able to see his machine more in depth. I will try to use ProcDump to see if I can have any info with this. I will also try to run another .NET 4.5.1 application to see if it related to his installation of .NET or if it is the application itself.

Is there any other way to investigate this issue ?

Thanks for the help.

FINAL EDIT : 
 - The two users with the issues had their computer formatted, since then the issue was not seen again for the moment.

Comment: Did you deploy a debug version?

Comment: @Rafalon No the application is built in Release configuration.

Comment: Does the crash happen in development too? If so, did you try debugging it?

Comment: @Rafalon I cannot replicate the crash on our computers at work, I might be able to install Visual Studio on the user's computer to try debugging it, but this will likely be the last thing I will try before asking him to format his computer. Only two users on the 3000 using the application are having this crash.

Comment: You mean only two of them actually reported this crash. How likely are the other 2998 to report it if it happened to them? Have you tested it on the computer of someone that didn't report the crash?

Comment: @Rafalon There might be other users with this issue but most of the other users have the application running fine. We have analytics showing that most of the users can use the application fine. For the moment only those two users reported the issue.

Comment: Posting the stack trace might help. You are now just asking about a random bug, "it doesn't work".

Comment: And add a handler for  AppDomain.UnhandledException as well.

Comment: @bommelding There is no stack trace, since the log does not work in this crash scenario. I am mostly asking on how should I investigate this rather than the fix itself. I will add more information once I will be able to access the user's computer and run a ProcDump, this might show the stacktrace.

Comment: @bommelding I will add this AppDomain.UnhandledException and keep you posted on this. Thanks for the tip

Comment: How to handle: have a form of fallback logging, for when logging fails or before it is set up. A simple file logger (System Diagnostics) or an EventSource in windows could help.

Comment: @bommelding I will look at this, do you have any implementation recommendation or link for this ?

Comment: I would write something simple around Trace.WriteError(). You will have to pluck and unroll the exception yourself. But configurable from app.config

Comment: There always is a crash log file for CLR unless the CLR itself crashed. Are you using `unsafe`? Any spots in your Code where you manually break using `Debugger.Break()`? Have you checked the Event log?

Comment: @X39 I am not using `unsafe` or `Debugger.Break()`. Where would I find the crash log file you are talking about ?

Comment: A simple google would have given you a link like this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2013/07/31/scan-the-windows-event-log-for-your-application-crashes-and-hangs/ short-answer is: check the actual event-log of the corresponding windows machine. The "crash" you experience tells you exactly what happened. Your application is somewhere at some point hitting a breakpoint that was written down in software. Either using Debugger.Break() or (being native assembly) by hitting `int 3` (assembly)

Comment: @X39 My bad I thought you were speaking of other types of logs not those events since I already talked about those in my question. I have looked at the events from one of the users and there is no lines added there at all after the crash. I will recheck there by myself on the next call session with them. The events I had were exported by the users themself they might have done something incorrectly, it is always better to check directly. Thank you for the information

Comment: This kind of issues might also be caused by a bug in the .NET runtime (e.g. JIT compiler). I have analyzed some crash dumps with that "a breakpoint is reached" exception. Make sure your customers always install .NET updates. You might want to have such a crash dump and debug it with WinDbg or even Visual Studio. When the app crashes next time, let the user make a crash dump of it (e.g. with the Task Manager).

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this? (Was your application using CefSharp?)